# Fake eyeball and eyeball which is fake

Tags: relative-clauses

[image]

This eye is a plastic eye for disabled people to wear.

1. Some old man wore a fake eye.
2. Some old man wore a eye which was fake.

Is it okay to switch sentence 1 with sentence 2?

Comment: A prosthetic eye, or ocular prosthesis, is often commonly called a "glass eye", not a "fake eye".

Comment: Both are okay. While **fake eye** and **glass eye** are popular descriptions,  **prosthetic eye** is a more accurate description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.

Some old man wore a fake eye.- simple sentence

Some old man wore an eye which was fake.- complex sentence

(a fake eye → a prosthetic eye)

Comment: We usually use _false_ rather than _fake_ for artificial body parts (e.g. false teeth) - but, as others have said, in modern  usage it's better to say _prosthetic_.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I have already mentioned  'a prosthetic eye'. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"Glass eye" (even if actually plastic) would be a more common term, but for precise use "prosthetic eye".

Don't use "fake" as this implies an intent to deceive.  A person with a prosthesis isn't trying to trick you, just make their life more comfortable.